# Can't get back from Sub Level 13

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

So I've done the mission at Sub Level 13 and got my E-gun. Now, I'm stuck at Titan Industrial Facility when I try to get back. All the doors out seem closed and I'm just running in circles with no way out it seem. Any one know how to get out? Story wise I'm on the mission Science and Violence.

Answer (score 3):

There is a hole in the room you finish the quest in that leads out of the room

Answer (score 2):

To exit with out forcing yourself to respawn:

- Accept SubLevel 13 Part 2's mission.
- There's a ladder that's above the dead guy
- Jump to it to climb out
- Follow the tunnel to a small cave then jump to a room.
- Listen to the ECHO.
- A wall panel will blow off, follow that. Note: It won't blow off until you've accepted Part 2 of the mission.

You should be able to figure the rest out from there.

Answer (score 1):

A cheap way to escape this is to join an online game in am area you have already unlocked and then leave you will spawn where the game was instead of sub level 13.

In addition to this you can actually use the same trick by just playing as a different character locally. The game will spawn you at the default New-U station for the area that your other character quit at as long as you have it unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

If you save and quit the game and then rejoin it will set your character at the entrance and you can just leave from there.